# How to retrieve my Gmail messages using Gmail API?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, google-api, gmail

### What I want to achieve:

---

I'm using the **[Gmail API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Gmail.v1/)** and basically I would like to connect to my GMail account to read my emails, of INBOX category, and get basic info for each message (title/subject, *from*, *to*, *date*, and the sender).

### Problems:

---

I'm trying to adapt **[this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet#step_3_set_up_the_sample)** Google sample, written in C#, to my own needs, I'm searching for a solution in C# or Vb.Net, no matter.

(Be aware that Google shows different code examples for different user-countries, so the code of that webpage maybe will not be the same for every one, that Google's logic really sucks.)

The problems I have with the code below, are these:

- I'm getting an empty value in `lblInbox.MessagesTotal` property.
- `msgItem.Raw` property is always empty too.
- I haven't yet discovered how to parse only the messages that are inside the INBOX category.
- I haven't yet discovered how to determine if a message is read or unread.
- I haven't yet discovered how to determine the basic info of a message (subject, from, to, date, sender).

This is what I've tried, note that when adapting the Google's sample, I assumed that `"user"` argument should be the Gmail user account name (`"MyEmail@GMail.com"`), but I'm not sure it should be that.

```vb
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
Imports Google.Apis.Gmail
Imports Google.Apis.Gmail.v1
Imports Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource

Public Class Form1 : Inherits Form

    Private Async Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Shown
        Await GmailTest()
    End Sub

    Public Async Function GmailTest() As Task
        Dim credential As UserCredential
        Using stream As New FileStream("C:\GoogleAPIKey.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            credential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                           {GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom},
                                                                           "MyEmail@GMail.com",
                                                                           CancellationToken.None)
        End Using

        ' Create the service.
        Dim service As New GmailService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
             .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
             .ApplicationName = "What I need to put here?"
        })

        ' Get the "INBOX" label/category.
        Dim lblReq As UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest = service.Users.Labels.List("me")
        Dim lblInbox As Data.Label = lblReq.Execute().Labels.Where(Function(lbl) lbl.Name = "INBOX").Single
        Dim msgCount As Integer? = lblInbox.MessagesTotal

        MsgBox("Messages Count: " & msgCount)

        If (msgCount <> 0) Then

            ' Define message parameters of request.
            Dim msgReq As UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest = service.Users.Messages.List("me")

            ' List messages of INBOX category.
            Dim messages As IList(Of Data.Message) = msgReq.Execute().Messages
            Console.WriteLine("Messages:")
            If (messages IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (messages.Count > 0) Then
                For Each msgItem As Data.Message In messages
                    MsgBox(msgItem.Raw)
                Next
            End If

        End If

    End Function

End Class
```

### Question:

---

I will ask for the most important need (however, any help to solve the other mentioned problems are very welcome):

- In C# or VB.Net, how can I obtain a collection to iterate **all** the emails that are in the INBOX group?.

---

### Update:

This is the code that I'm using right now, the intention is to retrieve a collection of all `Message`s of the specified mailbox *label*, the problem is that the `Payload` and `Body` member of `newMsg` object is null, so I can't read the email.

What I'm doing wrong?.

```vb
Public Async Function GetMessages(ByVal folder As Global.Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Label) As Task(Of List(Of Global.Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message))

    If Not (Me.isAuthorizedB) Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException(Me.authExceptionMessage)
    Else
        Dim msgsRequest As UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest = Me.client.Users.Messages.List("me")
        With msgsRequest
            .LabelIds = New Repeatable(Of String)({folder.Id})
            .MaxResults = 50
            '.Key = "YOUR API KEY"
        End With

        Dim msgsResponse As ListMessagesResponse = Await msgsRequest.ExecuteAsync()

        Dim messages As New List(Of Global.Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message)
        Do While True

            For Each msg As Global.Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message In msgsResponse.Messages
                Dim msgRequest As UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest = Me.client.Users.Messages.Get("me", msg.Id)
                msgRequest.Format = MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Full

                Dim newMsg As Message = Await msgRequest.ExecuteAsync()
                messages.Add(newMsg)
            Next msg

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(msgsResponse.NextPageToken) Then
                msgsRequest.PageToken = msgsResponse.NextPageToken
                msgsResponse = Await msgsRequest.ExecuteAsync()
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If

        Loop

        Return messages

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: "user"  is used by filedatastore to change the name of the stored credentials.   it can be any random string.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for that useful info, then now I'm totally missunderstanding how and where to specify what Gmail user account I want to get access.

Comment: You don't really when the user authenticates the application they give you access then.   You don't specify it really they do by authenticating your code.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Currently for some reason or another many of the properties are coming back `null` from any of the requests. We can still get around that if we have a list of the email ids. We then can use these email ids to send out another request to retrieve further details: `from`, `date`, `subject`, and `body`. [@DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36449261) was on the right track as well, but not close enough about the headers as it has changed recently which will require a few more requests.

```
private async Task getEmails()
{
    try
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly, GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify },
                "NAME OF ACCOUNT NOT EMAIL ADDRESS",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
            );
        }

        var gmailService = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        var emailListRequest = gmailService.Users.Messages.List("EMAILADDRESSHERE");
        emailListRequest.LabelIds = "INBOX";
        emailListRequest.IncludeSpamTrash = false;
        //emailListRequest.Q = "is:unread"; // This was added because I only wanted unread emails...

        // Get our emails
        var emailListResponse = await emailListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        if (emailListResponse != null && emailListResponse.Messages != null)
        {
            // Loop through each email and get what fields you want...
            foreach (var email in emailListResponse.Messages)
            {
                var emailInfoRequest = gmailService.Users.Messages.Get("EMAIL ADDRESS HERE", email.Id);
                // Make another request for that email id...
                var emailInfoResponse = await emailInfoRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                if (emailInfoResponse != null)
                {
                    String from = "";
                    String date = "";
                    String subject = "";
                    String body = "";
                    // Loop through the headers and get the fields we need...
                    foreach (var mParts in emailInfoResponse.Payload.Headers)
                    {
                        if (mParts.Name == "Date")
                        {
                            date = mParts.Value; 
                        }
                        else if(mParts.Name == "From" )
                        {
                            from = mParts.Value;
                        }
                        else if (mParts.Name == "Subject")
                        {
                            subject = mParts.Value;
                        }

                        if (date != "" && from != "")
                        {
                            if (emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts == null && emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body != null)
                            {
                                body = emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body.Data;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                body = getNestedParts(emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts, "");
                            }
                            // Need to replace some characters as the data for the email's body is base64
                            String codedBody = body.Replace("-", "+");
                            codedBody = codedBody.Replace("_", "/");
                            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(codedBody);
                            body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);                               

                            // Now you have the data you want...                         
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }           
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to get messages!", "Failed Messages!", MessageBoxButtons.OK); 
    }
}

static String getNestedParts(IList<MessagePart> part, string curr)
{
    string str = curr;
    if (part == null)
    {
        return str;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var parts in part)
        {
            if (parts.Parts  == null)
            {
                if (parts.Body != null && parts.Body.Data != null)
                {
                    str += parts.Body.Data;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return getNestedParts(parts.Parts, str);
            }
        }

        return str;
    }        
}
```

Currently, this method will retrieve all email ids and for each email id get the `subject`,`from`, `date` and `body` of each email. There are comments throughout the method. If there is something you do not understand, please let me know. On another note: **this was tested again before posting this as an answer**.

Comment: At downvoter, would you please explain why the downvote? When not doing so it doesn't ***benefit anyone***. Maybe I am missing something here, but the answer provided does exactly what the OP needed help with along with explanation. If you feel this is incomplete, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for answer!, I think too an answer like this DOESN'T deserve a downvote, world is full of people with no criteria. Could you please explain **body = getNestedParts(...)**?, I will test your code in some minutes.

Comment: I'm still unable to retrieve the body, **emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body** is null (then **...Body.Data** member too), in the code provided just checking whether the property is null or not, and then you call **getNestedParts(...)**, which Is missing.

Comment: @ElektroStudios oh my bad, forgot that function sorry about that! I will get it when I get home as I can't access it here from work. The function goes through nested parts to get the body...

Comment: @ElektroStudios aside from missing function do you get the other stuff back?

Comment: Yes don't worry, the "parts" are retrieved properlly except the body, however, the request also processes emails of "Categories\Social" label too, instead of only "Inbox" label, I don't know why happens that and/or how to filter it properlly, but if is too much tedious to answer then I'll publish another question about it don't worry.

Comment: @ElektroStudios `//emailListRequest.Q = "is:unread";` that line make sure to uncomment as this will only give you the inbox emails that are not read yet. Please make sure you seen the `emailListRequest.LabelIds = "INBOX";` code, its above in a comment and ***should*** only return `inbox` emails . Also I will get that function when I get to my machine after work sorry about that, but glad to hear you are getting the parts now!

Comment: @ElektroStudios sorry it took some time, I updated the code above that was missing the function. You should be good to go now.

Comment: The solution provided is not working properlly, the base64 related methodolofy will fail and throw exception because some emails are encoded in base64, and some other aren't, then, it should ensure it is base64 encoded before try decode!, how I could know that info?, it is specified somewhere on the message properties/parts? (a try/catch expecting to fail will be very expensive). Also, about the "Inbox" label, I already have specified only that label as in your code, exactlly the same, but it is getting also emails from "Categories" label.

Comment: Also, I'm getting empty "bodies" (nul strings) for emails that are conversations :(, why?.

Comment: Google could be the 1st shark company on the world but... their APi is trash, because Microsoft's Outlook API compared to this is a lot friendlly and easier than Google, a lot of work just to retrieve a damn message body?, why so tedious and annonying, Google?. See, even you that you are a lot more experienced than me with Google API, you are having problems with the algorithm because as I mentioned all messages ARE NOT base64 (just few, I don't know why), and other messages returns an empty body, pf... why?.

Comment: @ElektroStudios I have noticed that. Not sure at the moment as that has been as far as I have got with it myself. 1 thing I did was put a catch around that base64 if it fails it's not base64... So far it's worked for me.

Comment: Well, the API says this: "**payload.body: The message part body for this part, which may be empty for container MIME message parts.**", I'm not sure if this is the case on where that applies to empty bodies, but I checked all the message parts and didn't found any encoded or decoded value that stores the body message. You did a lot of work, I'll accept the answer and I'm very grateful with your help, however, if you have any idea about how to retrieve the bodies when they are empty...any kind of hint, then please tell me.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I will look more into this but Google's APIs are dirty and incomplete. Its not per say the APIs but the underlying data that comes back from the call. If I find something out I will be sure to update and post here.

Comment: @Codexer:   almost there on the base64 decode, you did the URL decode, but you just need to pad the string with == so it is the right length.  (and start by pulling off any = in the string, then re-pad, I added an example as a response below.).  Thank you! your code was super-helpful to me. Also, might take the body read out of the loop that reads all the headers, I think the body is being read once for every mime header.

Comment: Why do you use `if (date != "" && from != "")` for getting body? I mean how does these conditions matter? How you'd be sure `emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts == null && emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body == null` does not take place?

Comment: But why not add these conditions in `if (emailInfoResponse != null)`?

Comment: @zaggler can we implement same coding to console application(act as webjob) ? I was implemented fetch mail from gmail, but the token is expired after few days. Can we do it automatically scheduler?. Hope you understand my issue.

Comment: @PrinceAntonyG yes, essentially you could.

Comment: @zaggler Token will expiry after 3600 seconds , then how this windows service will run to fetch the mail? earlier i was got the token expired / grant permission error.

Answer (score 13):

sorry this is not an answer, i can't add a comment to Zaggler's answer(just joined), so just post as a new answer, Zaggler's answer is very good, but there is a small problem. when the email body has more then one part. the Convert.FromBase64..... doesn't work on two joined base64 strings. so an exception will be occure. better convert then joined the body parts.

some one ask for the code, and here is the completed tested code. most of them are copied from Zaggler, but i end up with some exceptions. so i traced down to the problem described above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace GmailTests
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailModify };
        static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart2.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Gmail API service.
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


            var re = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
            re.LabelIds = "INBOX";
            re.Q = "is:unread"; //only get unread;

            var res = re.Execute();

            if (res != null && res.Messages != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("there are {0} emails. press any key to continue!", res.Messages.Count);
                Console.ReadKey();

                foreach (var email in res.Messages)
                {
                    var emailInfoReq = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", email.Id);
                    var emailInfoResponse = emailInfoReq.Execute();

                    if (emailInfoResponse != null)
                    {
                        String from = "";
                        String date = "";
                        String subject = "";
                        String body = "";
                        //loop through the headers and get the fields we need...
                        foreach (var mParts in emailInfoResponse.Payload.Headers)
                        {
                            if (mParts.Name == "Date")
                            {
                                date = mParts.Value;
                            }
                            else if (mParts.Name == "From")
                            {
                                from = mParts.Value;
                            }
                            else if (mParts.Name == "Subject")
                            {
                                subject = mParts.Value;
                            }

                            if (date != "" && from != "")
                            {
                                if (emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts == null && emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body != null)
                                    body = DecodeBase64String(emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body.Data);
                                else
                                    body = GetNestedBodyParts(emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts, "");

                                //now you have the data you want....

                            }

                        }

                        //Console.Write(body);
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}  --  {1}  -- {2}", subject, date, email.Id);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static String DecodeBase64String(string s)
        {
            var ts = s.Replace("-", "+");
            ts = ts.Replace("_", "/");
            var bc = Convert.FromBase64String(ts);
            var tts = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bc);

            return tts;
        }

        static String GetNestedBodyParts(IList<MessagePart> part, string curr)
        {
            string str = curr;
            if (part == null)
            {
                return str;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var parts in part)
                {
                    if (parts.Parts == null)
                    {
                        if (parts.Body != null && parts.Body.Data != null)
                        {
                            var ts = DecodeBase64String(parts.Body.Data);
                            str += ts;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return GetNestedBodyParts(parts.Parts, str);
                    }
                }

                return str;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your contribution can be good if you rewrite your answer a bit. Can you give an example how to convert and join the body parts?

Comment: thank for fixing the exception which I was getting. (y)

Comment: can we implement in a windows(console) application?

Answer (score 4):

First: up-vote @codexer 's answer.

Second, use the following function in his code to decode the base64URL encoded body.  Google not only base64 encoded the body, it is also URL encoded :-/

```
/// <summary>
    /// Turn a URL encoded base64 encoded string into readable UTF-8 string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sInput">base64 URL ENCODED string.</param>
    /// <returns>UTF-8 formatted string</returns>
    private string DecodeURLEncodedBase64EncodedString(string sInput)
    {
        string sBase46codedBody = sInput.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/").Replace("=", String.Empty);  //get rid of URL encoding, and pull any current padding off.
        string sPaddedBase46codedBody = sBase46codedBody.PadRight(sBase46codedBody.Length + (4 - sBase46codedBody.Length % 4) % 4, '=');  //re-pad the string so it is correct length.
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(sPaddedBase46codedBody);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The user parameter in GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is just used by FileDatastore to store your credentials check my tutorial [Google .net – FileDatastore demystified](http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/) for more information.

My VB.net is very rusty like 6 years rusty but in C# you could do something like this

```
UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List("Users email address");
var response = request.Execute();

foreach (var item in response.Messages) {
     Console.WriteLine(item.Payload.Headers);            
 }
```

MessageResource.ListRequest returns a list of message objects you can loop though them.

[Users.Messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource-representations) contains header which should have the subject and the to and from.

I also have a really old C# tutorial on [gmail](http://www.daimto.com/how-to-access-gmail-with-c-net/) that might help.

**Update to answer your update:**

What happens when you remove:

```
.LabelIds = New Repeatable(Of String)({folder.Id})
```

> labelIds  string  Only return messages with labels that match all of the specified label IDs.

It appears you are sending a folder id.  try using [user.lables.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list) which returns Lists all labels in the user's mailbox

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but in my case `Payloads` property is always nul (a nul reference) so its members are nul too, why?, then I can't see the email body or anything, however, seems that the response is done ok, because at least I can use the `Item.Id` property and is not empty, but I'm experiencing the same problem I explained, nul reference objects and empty strings for the members of the returned response, I can't access any, just the Id and other numeric properties.

Comment: @DalmTo the above code only returns the list of emails, pretty much only their ids. Then another request is required for each email id to get the headers and their parts... These parts contain that detail.

Comment: @zaggler Could you please explain which kind of request is necessary to do for each message?, I'm getting crazy about. could you add an answer to extend 
DaImTo's answer?

Comment: @ElektroStudios I could indeed. I'm going to finish my outside work and then I will post a solution for you.

Comment: @zaggler Thanks, After obtained a collection of message ids with `MessagesResource.ListRequest`, I tried to perform a `MessagesResource.GetRequest` passing the message ids and setting the format param to `MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Full`, but this kind of request seems doesn't returns the data I want, because `Message.Payload` member still null in the ne Message obtained, or maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: updated for your update also I almost think you could have made that into a separate question.  searching on labels.

Answer (score 1):

```
UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest getReq = null;
Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message msg = null;
getReq = gmailServiceObj.Users.Messages.Get(userEmail, MessageID);
getReq.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Raw;
msg = getReq.Execute();
string converted = msg.Raw.Replace('-', '+');
converted = converted.Replace('_', '/');

byte[] decodedByte = Convert.FromBase64String(converted);
converted = null;
f_Path = Path.Combine(m_CloudParmsObj.m_strDestinationPath,MessageID + ".eml");

if (!Directory.Exists(m_CloudParmsObj.m_strDestinationPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(m_CloudParmsObj.m_strDestinationPath);

// Create eml file
File.WriteAllBytes(f_Path, decodedByte);
```

We can get the .eml file with all message properties like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
          codedBody = codedBody.Replace(" ", "+");
          codedBody = codedBody.Replace("=", "+");
```

to parse the body part I recommend adding these lines of code as well

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).