# Selenium not secure gmail

Tags: c#, selenium

So i was trying to make a bot, and one if its tasks requires it to read en email.

The bot is made using c# and selenium

But when it trys to login to gmail i get:

The browser may not be safe

And it doesn't let the bot login.

Is there any workaround for this?

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace WTFSkinsFC
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = "gmail.com";
        driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1536, 824);
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".JDAKTe:nth-child(2) > 
  .lCoei")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("identifierId")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("identifierId")).SendKeys("Email");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("identifierId")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".H2SoFe")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("Password");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What does "I can't log into gmail" mean? What happens when you try?

Comment: How are you trying to log into Gmail?  Via the Web UI with Selenium?  Have you tried the Gmail api? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Comment: it says browser or app may not be secure

Comment: Anbd im using selenium

Comment: Please add more information, like script code (omit sensitive info), exact error response, etc.

Comment: Added code :) maybe its easier to understand now

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access gmail, you're better off using IMAP/POP3 connectors than selenium and/or the UI. I believe there is also a gmail API you can access instead of IMAP/POP

Take a look at [How to retrieve my Gmail messages using Gmail API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448193/how-to-retrieve-my-gmail-messages-using-gmail-api)